# How to disable Remove Project permission for owners by default in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

We use the Omnibus GitLab CE system with LDAP authentication.

When a group owner remove a project, earlier version would not delete the project in the storage, it just renames them us projectname-deleted.git. Current version is deleting the project from storage after rename.

I don't want project to be deleted from storage, I see writing a hook as the only option, is there any better way to do it ? Or Removing delete project is an option ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a try on this --

```
+++ b/gitlab-rails/app/policies/project_policy.rb
@@ -90,7 +90,7 @@ class ProjectPolicy < BasePolicy
     enable :change_namespace
     enable :change_visibility_level
     enable :rename_project
-    enable :remove_project
+    # enable :remove_project
     enable :archive_project
     enable :remove_fork_project
     enable :destroy_merge_request
```